# How does Joomla create the Rules value in assets table?

Tags: joomla, field, rules

I would like to know how does Joomla create the values in the Rule field in the #__assets table.

I believe that the files where they are created might be:

libraries\joomla\database\table\content.php

libraries\joomla\database\table.php

I have tried to find the code which does this but I either don't find it or what I do find just don't understand it. I need to know how Joomla creates these values in this field to be able to make my own process.

Comment: did you get your answer. if yes please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every component controls its rules with an access.xml file. You will find these in the administrator/components/com_whatever folder.

Where specific rules are managed depends on the type of asset.

Component level rules are managed in com_config with the component mvc, meaning that when a user clicks the options button in the component they set the rules for the component.

Item level rules (such as for categories and articles) are managed in the form for those items via a field with type="rules."

Global rules are managed by com_config with the application mvc and the UI is in  global configuration.

JTable manages storing this in the assets table.